# Shape of 3-order tensors in $O_h, O, T_d$ and $D_3$ point gruops

Tags: tensors

How does one calculate the shape of higher order $(Dimension>2)$ tensors in respect of point group symmetry?

I understand that you have to use transformation matrix corresponding to a symmetry operation of a group and then equate the obtained coefficients to the old ones (since after a symmetry operation the system does not change).

I need to find shapes of 3 order tensors in $O_h, O, T_d$ and $D_3$ point gruops.

An example of $C_3(x_3)$ on a $T_{ijk}$ would be much appreciated. How do I do the matrix tensor multiplication?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Will do form now on. Thank You for the link!